# Which data structure would be best for this?

Tags: c++, data-structures

For my game, when an object enters a sensor, I need to add it to a list, and when the object leaves the sensor it needs to be removed from that list. I also need to quickly be able to find that object.

So essentially:

I need it to do:
quick adding, quick removal and quick find.

What sort of data structure would be best for this given that at any given time, the stucture will have about 10 objects.

Thanks

Comment: > I need it to do: quick adding, quick removal and quick find.
QuickStruct is the way to go

Comment: An imaginary ideal data structure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With 10 objects anything will do (`std::vector`, `deque` or `set`), and nobody can tell which one performs better before profiling.

If you don't know what to use, perhaps you'll find that [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) has a nicer syntax for looking up elements. This is what I would use in this situation, because I wouldn't like to write `std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), sensor)` where I could simply write `s.find(sensor)`.

*Don't use `std::list` though, as a general advice. You need a compelling reason to use linked lists in C++ (constant time splicing is one, absence of iterator invalidation is another). Other data structures perform better for most operations (except splicing). Here, I don't see any point in using `list` rather than eg. `set`.*

Comment: Set provide good look-up speed, but insertion and removal of elements is not as fast as lists. Should be considered which operation is the more often executed.

Comment: @neodelphi: Figuring out *where* to insert or remove is faster on sets than on lists. So I wouldn't be as categoric as you are. Moreover, inserting and removing in vectors of 10 elements is likely to be much faster than in lists (for data locality reasons). It is really not clear which container is better performancewise, but I strongly believe that `std::list` is behind. And it is a good idea to force oneself to use lists only where required, since they have very poor overall performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `std::list` since it is perfectly adapted for insertion and removal of elements.

Comment: I wouldn't even say it's good for the insertion of elements. It's quite slow at that.

Comment: Because a linked list has to dynamically allocate a node for every single element. That's slow.

Comment: Insertion of an element in a vector is much slower ! For a huge set of objects, insertion in a linked list may have great performance since it is in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Quick adding, quick removing and quick finding, you don't want much do you! Given what you said I would say linked list, but it also depends on how frequent adds, deletes and finds are. If you're finding much more frequently than you are adding or deleting things change.

Really the only way is to try a few different choices and time them.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Linked List would be best. Given the small size, the act of shifting pointers would not impact performance.